solidity - Error: execution reverted: "ERC721: invalid token ID"
Error: execution reverted: "ERC721: invalid token ID" when I trying fetchMarketItem after I used cancelSale
Error: execution reverted: "ERC721: invalid token ID" (action="call", data="0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000184552433732313a20696e76616c696420746f6b656e2049440000000000000000", reason="ERC721: invalid token ID", transaction={ "data": "0xc87b56dd0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "to": "0xc54BdD77D409Dd558F48B5B3fab4cc7b1b7b1A42" }, invocation=null, revert={ "args": [ "ERC721: invalid token ID" ], "name": "Error", "signature": "Error(string)" }, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.12.1)
below is my contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold;

    uint256 listingPrice = 0.000001 ether;
    address payable owner;

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

    struct MarketItem {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
    }

    event MarketItemCreated(
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address seller,
        address owner,
        uint256 price,
        bool sold
    );

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "only owner of the marketplace can change the listing price"
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor() ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "METT") {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override(ERC721URIStorage) returns (string memory) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: invalid token ID");
    return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
}
    /* Updates the listing price of the contract */
    function updateListingPrice(uint256 _listingPrice)
        public
        payable
        onlyOwner
    {
        require(
            owner == msg.sender,
            "Only marketplace owner can update listing price."
        );
        listingPrice = _listingPrice;
    }

    /* Returns the listing price of the contract */
    function getListingPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return listingPrice;
    }

    /* Mints a token and lists it in the marketplace */
    function createToken(string memory tokenURI, uint256 price)
        public
        payable
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();

        _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);
        createMarketItem(newTokenId, price);
        return newTokenId;
    }

    function createMarketItem(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) private {
        require(price > 0, "Price must be at least 1 wei");
        require(
            msg.value == listingPrice,
            "Price must be equal to listing price"
        );

        idToMarketItem[tokenId] = MarketItem(
            tokenId,
            payable(msg.sender),
            payable(address(this)),
            price,
            false
        );

        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
        emit MarketItemCreated(
            tokenId,
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            price,
            false
        );
    }

    /* allows someone to resell a token they have purchased */
    function resellToken(uint256 tokenId, uint256 price) public payable {
        require(
            idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner == msg.sender,
            "Only item owner can perform this operation"
        );
        require(
            msg.value == listingPrice,
            "Price must be equal to listing price"
        );
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = false;
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].price = price;
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(address(this));
        _itemsSold.decrement();

        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), tokenId);
    }

    /* Creates the sale of a marketplace item */
    /* Transfers ownership of the item, as well as funds between parties */
    function createMarketSale(uint256 tokenId) public payable {
        uint256 price = idToMarketItem[tokenId].price;
        require(
            msg.value == price,
            "Please submit the asking price in order to complete the purchase"
        );
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = true;
        _itemsSold.increment();
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
        payable(owner).transfer(listingPrice);
        payable(idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller).transfer(msg.value);
        idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(address(0));
    }

    /* Returns all unsold market items */
    function fetchMarketItems() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 itemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        uint256 unsoldItemCount = _tokenIds.current() - _itemsSold.current();
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](unsoldItemCount);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            uint256 tokenId = i + 1;
            if (_exists(tokenId) && idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner == address(this) && idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller != address(0) && !idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold) {
                items[currentIndex] = idToMarketItem[tokenId];
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }

    /* Returns only items that a user has purchased */
    function fetchMyNFTs() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        uint256 itemCount = 0;
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
                itemCount += 1;
            }
        }

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].owner == msg.sender) {
                uint256 currentId = i + 1;
                MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    /* Returns only items a user has listed */
    function fetchItemsListed() public view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 totalItemCount = _tokenIds.current();
        uint256 itemCount = 0;
        uint256 currentIndex = 0;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
                itemCount += 1;
            }
        }

        MarketItem[] memory items = new MarketItem[](itemCount);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalItemCount; i++) {
            if (idToMarketItem[i + 1].seller == msg.sender) {
                uint256 currentId = i + 1;
                MarketItem storage currentItem = idToMarketItem[currentId];
                items[currentIndex] = currentItem;
                currentIndex += 1;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
    /*BurnNFT*/ 
    function burnNFT(uint256 tokenId) public {
    require(idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner == msg.sender, "Only item owner can burn token");
    _burn(tokenId);
    delete idToMarketItem[tokenId];
    }

    /*CancelSell*/
    function cancelSale(uint256 tokenId) public {
    require(idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller == msg.sender, "Only item seller can cancel sale");
    require(!idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold, "Item has been sold, cannot cancel sale");

    idToMarketItem[tokenId].sold = true;
    idToMarketItem[tokenId].owner = payable(msg.sender);
    idToMarketItem[tokenId].seller = payable(address(0)); // Đặt seller về địa chỉ zero
    _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokenId);
    }
}

Tôi tiếp tục nhận được lỗi tương tự. Bạn có thể giúp tôi xác định nguyên nhân và giải quyết nó được không?
Cảm ơn bạn rất nhiều trước
